# Add decimal years in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I can add years to a date in `PHP` like

```
$yr = '2020-03-28';
$dt = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+2 years'));
//Output 28.03.2022
```

How can I add decimal numbers of years in `PHP`?
I want to do something like

```
$yr = '2020-03-28';
$dt = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+1.25 years'));
//Output 01.01.1970
```

Thanks

Comment: you can't. You need to write like that: `echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+1 years 3 months'));`

Comment: @delirehberi thanks, but the thing is the value `1.25` is coming from `DB`, hence it is not feasible to convert it manually.

Comment: Can you multiply it by 365 (and round down to the nearest integer) and add that many days, e.g. `$dt = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+456 days'));`?

Comment: @kmoser yes great, thanks. can you post as an answer?

Comment: @abbas Done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply it by 365, round down to the nearest integer, and add that many days, e.g.:

```
$years = 1.25;
$days = floor( $years * 365 ); // Note: not accurate for leap years!
$dt = date('d.m.Y', strtotime("+$days days"));
```